# Compiler error: Stack too deep

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, solc, compilation, zksync

I am getting this error when trying to deploy my smart contract using `zkSync` but on a different chain (Polygon Mumbai):

```
CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.
   --> @matterlabs/zksync-contracts/l2/system-contracts/BootloaderUtilities.sol:103:34:
    |
103 |             uint256 listLength = encodedNonce.length +
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

This are all my files:

**hardhat.config.ts**

```
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc";
const { pk } = require('./.secrets.json');

module.exports = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "1.3.1",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    settings: {},
  },
  defaultNetwork: "zkSyncTestnet",
  networks: {
    zkSyncTestnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev",
      ethNetwork: "goerli", // Can also be the RPC URL of the network (e.g. `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<API_KEY>`)
      zksync: true,
      accounts: [pk]
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: "https://matic-mumbai.chainstacklabs.com/",
      chainId: 80001,
      gasPrice: "auto",
      accounts: [pk],
      zksync: false
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**Greeter.sol**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Greeter {
    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

**deploy.ts**

```
import { Wallet } from "zksync-web3";
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { Deployer } from "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
import { pk } from "../.secrets.json";

// An example of a deploy script that will deploy and call a simple contract.
export default async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  console.log(`Running deploy script for the Greeter contract`);

  // Initialize the wallet.
  const wallet = new Wallet(pk);

  // Create deployer object and load the artifact of the contract you want to deploy.
  const deployer = new Deployer(hre, wallet);
  const artifact = await deployer.loadArtifact("Greeter");

  // Estimate contract deployment fee
  const greeting = "Hi there!";
  //const deploymentFee = await deployer.estimateDeployFee(artifact, [greeting]);

  const greeterContract = await deployer.deploy(artifact, [greeting]);

  //obtain the Constructor Arguments
  console.log("constructor args:" + greeterContract.interface.encodeDeploy([greeting]));

  // Show the contract info.
  const contractAddress = greeterContract.address;
  console.log(`${artifact.contractName} was deployed to ${contractAddress}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point there was a bug in v1.3.1 so try deleting all the compilers from the cache folder in `/Users/<YOUR USERNAME>/Library/Caches/hardhat-nodejs/compilers-v2/zksolc/` and try again. It will download the corresponding compiler automatically.

Also, make sure you're using the latest versions of the hardhat plugins ([hardhat-zksync-solc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc) and [hardhat-zksync-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy)) and [the compiler](https://github.com/matter-labs/zksolc-bin).